# In the equation for acceleration (with known $v$, $u$ and $s$) why velocity is squared and displacement is multiplied by 2?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, displacement

In the following equation $$a = \frac{v^2 − u^2 } {2s} ,$$ where $v$ is the final velocity, $u$ is the initial velocity, and $s$ is displacement. Why is velocity squared and displacement multiplied by 2?

Comment: Have you tried to derive this formula? Start from $v=u+a t$ and $s=u t+\frac{1}{2}a t^2$.

Comment: In these simpler equations for how velocity and displacement depend on *time*, do you understand why the second term in the second one has $t$ squared and a factor of 1/2? These two things, plus algebra, lead to the velocities being squared in your equation, and the displacement being multiplied by 2.

Comment: If you like this question you may also enjoy reading [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89590/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 1):

The kinematic equation for constant acceleration $$a = \dfrac{(v^2 − u^2 )} {2s}$$ can be changed to the following equation where $m$ is the mass of the object and $F$ is the force acting on the object.

$$\frac 12 m v^2 - \frac 12 m u^2 = ma\, s = F\, s$$

The left hand side is the change in the kinetic energy of the object and the right hand side is the work done on the object by an external force.

Comment: I don't think this is a worthwhile direction for this kinematics question. G Smith's comment is far more likely the right way to go.