# If we divide the second equation of motion by time $t$, why don't we get the first equation of motion where has $1/2$ come from?

Tags: kinematics, differentiation, integration, calculus

The first equation of motion is $v = u + at$.

The second equation of motion is $s = ut + \frac{at^2}{2}$.

If we divide the second equation of motion by time $t$, why don't we get the first equation of motion where has $1/2$ come from?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Why there is a $\frac{1}{2}$ in the distance formula $d=\frac{1}{2}at^2$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89590/2451) and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

The "$v$" in the first equation is the instantaneous velocity at the end of the time $t$, starting at an instantaneous velocity $u$ and accelerating for that time at a rate $a$.

On the other hand, the "$s$" in the second equation is the distance travelled under the above conditions.  So, if you divide the second equation by $t$, the left-hand side will be the **average** velocity over the motion.

Since the object starts at a velocity $u$ and adds $at$ to its velocity by the end, it's logical that the average velocity is $u+\frac12 at$.

Bottom line, any equation that is quoted without a definition of every term (the "wheres) is worse than useless.

Answer (score 0):

Because distance, $s$, is the *integral* of velocity with respect to time.

So, given $v = u + at$, you can integrate this to get
$$\begin{align}
s &= \int u + at\,dt\\
   &= ut + \frac{at^2}{2} + s_0
\end{align}$$
Where $s_0$ is a constant of integration.  If you further say that $s = 0$ when $t = 0$ you end up with $s = ut + at^2/2$.