# Motion of free fall

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, integration, calculus, free-fall

We know that according to law of free falls object, all bodies fall with the same constant acceleration. But in distance formula ($s = \frac12 gt^2$), why the acceleration is just half?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89590/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straight line graph of velocity against time for constant acceleration from zero velocity is shown below.

[image]

The area under such a graph (a triangle) is the displacement, $s = \frac 12 \cdot gt\cdot t = \frac 12 gt^2$.

Note that the average velocity is $\frac{v-0}{2}$ and so the displacement is $s=\frac{v-0}{2}\cdot t = \frac {gt}{2} \cdot t = \frac 12 gt^2$ as before.

If there is an initial velocity $u$ then the displacement (tapezium or triangle plus rectangle) is $s = ut+\frac 12gt^2$ which can be found using the graph below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The acceleration is not half of $g$. It is equal to $g$. The expression you are referring to is obtained by integration.
\begin{align}
&\frac{d^2s}{dt^2} = g \\
\implies &\frac{ds}{dt} = gt+c_1 \\ 
\implies &s = \frac{1}{2}gt^2+c_1 t+c_2
\end{align}

If you take the initial conditions as $s(0) = 0$ and $s'(0) = 0$, you will get the expression.