# Graph of position vs time under constant acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

In [the answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/89597/323311), the person showed a graph of position vs time (for constant acceleration), his graph looks like $$x\propto t$$ but in reality, $$x\propto t^2$$ under constant acceleration. Isn't his answer wrong? Or didn't he mean to graph position vs time squared? $$x=\frac{1}{2}gt^2$$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it involves a specific mistake the original poster made and it is unlikely it will benefit future users.

Answer (score 4):

He didn't show $x \propto t$, he showed $v \propto t$ ! Have a look at the vertical axis:
[image: vertical axis]

As $v = \frac{x}{t}$, you have no contradiction and $v \propto t \Longleftrightarrow \frac{x}{t} \propto t \Longleftrightarrow x \propto t^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The graph is accurate. Cause they plotted velocity vs time not position vs time. And $$v\propto t$$ using the function they found the graph.

Comment: I was planning to remove the answer but the upvote represent someone else became curious of the question that's why instead of deleting I answered my mistake

Comment: You answered faster than me :)