# Argument for distance in terms of acceleration

Tags: kinematics, integration, calculus

This, I know might perfectly be a very stupid question. But trying to make sense of it in terms of a very simple explanation. For distance $d=vt$. Velocity might be another function of time $v=at$. The formula states that (if $v_0=d_0=0$) $d=\frac{1}{2}at^2$. I have seen the mean speed theorem, but do not get why simple substitution would give an incorrect answer ($d=at^2$).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89590/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

v=at is valid for constant acceleration.

d=vt is valid for constant velocity. But if there is acceleration, then the velocity is not constant.

For constant acceleration, starting from standstill, velocity at time t is v=at. As the velocity is varying linearly with time, it follows that the average velocity form standstill until time t is ½at (plot v against t on an x-y graph and it will be obvious).
The distance travelled over the time period from standstill to time t is the average velocity multiplied by the time, which gives d=½at<sup>2</sup>